# Extract token from URL resonse with Regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: regex

Here is the URL returned:

[https://192.168.1.1:9006/payinterface/ThreeDSChecker/Check3DS?token=707087d7-7b75-42bc-8564-69a13c403b8a&MID=0000&TID=000000"](https://192.168.1.1:9006/payinterface/ThreeDSChecker/Check3DS?token=707087d7-7b75-42bc-8564-69a13c403b8a&MID=0000&TID=000000%22),

I need to extract the token value,
When I use this expression token=(.*&M+) I got the below values

```
Match count: 1
Match[1][0]=token=707087d7-7b75-42bc-8564-69a13c403b8a&M
Match[1][1]=707087d7-7b75-42bc-8564-69a13c403b8a&M
```

I need to get only value of the token without the "&M" in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `M+` after brackets to get value until &M

```
token=(.*)&M
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need the regular expressions here, you can go for the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) and provide `token=` as the left boundary and `&` as the right boundary:

[image]

It would be easier, faster and consume less resources.

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)

If you want to continue with regular expressions you can go for:

```
token=(.+?)&
```

[image]

or if you're looking for a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)-like structure:

```
([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12})
```

[image]